# Member function pointer for overloaded member function

Tags: c++, function-pointers

Note: following code example is not a real code, the real code is far more complicated to paste it here, so the example may seems ridiculous, but it is not important.

```
struct Base
{
    void beginEvent(int a)
    {
        impl(a, &Base::onBeginEvent, &Base::onBeginEvent);
    }

    void endEvent(int a)
    {
        impl(a, &Base::onEndEvent, &Base::onEndEvent);
    }

    void impl(int a, void (Base::*func1)(int), void (Base::*func2)(int, int))
    {
        //some complicated behavior
        //...
        (this->*func1)(a);
        (this->*func2)(a, -a);
    }

    virtual void onBeginEvent(int a){}
    virtual void onBeginEvent(int a, int negativeA){}
    virtual void onEndEvent(int a){}
    virtual void onEndEvent(int a, int negativeA){}
};
```

and

```
struct Derived : public Base
{
    void onBeginEvent(int a) { std::cout << a << "\n"; }
    void onEndEvent(int a, int b) { std::cout << a << "==(-(" << b << "))\n"; }
};

int main() 
{
    Derived d;

    d.beginEvent(3);
    d.endEvent(9);

    return 0;
}
```

My question is:
is it really necessary define `impl` function the way it takes `void (Base::*func1)(int)` and `void (Base::*func2)(int, int)` even though I know that it is one member function pointer (`&Base::onBeginEvent` in this case)?

When provided only one of them I obviously get too few resp. to much arguments when calling. I do not want variadic function or something, I want finite number of method which can Base provide to Derived. Derived could want only one, or any subset of provided method to be called. But I know, they will be just overloads on same symbol. My goal is not to make it works with some crazy workarounds, I just want to know, if I could reduce the posted code.

: [Full ideone working example](http://ideone.com/3WkSsu)

**EDIT**
Thme impl method in my real code is quite complicated, bud the same for begin and end just with different call at the end of impl...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say `...the way it takes void (Base::*func1)(int) and void (Base::*func2)(int, int) even though I know that it is one member function pointer...`, And who told you they are both one function? Just because 2 functions have the same name, it never mean they are same function.
Their address and every thing except their name are different. So they are 2 different functions not one function

Comment: The substance is correct, but I feel like the tone is needlessly harsh.

Comment: thank you for pointing that out. What is the answer though? There is no way to change `impl(a, &Base::onBeginEvent, &Base::onBeginEvent);`to `impl(a, &Base::onBeginEvent);` ?

Comment: Of course no! You may other function `foo` and that never change the fact that they are to unrelated functions, one of them can send an spaceship to the moon and other try to find a thief. The only thing that cause you feel they have a connection is they have same name. But do computers and specially our lovely C++ understand it?? But you can write a macro to write that for you if you really want it

Answer (score 1):

How about replacing the function pointers with polymorphic behavior, which is effectively the same thing, but more OO, more intuitive, and easier to read.

Here's an example:

```
struct Base
{
    void beginEvent(int a)
    {
        implBegin(a);
    }

    void endEvent(int a)
    {
        implEnd(a);
    }

// Consider making the rest of the methods protected    
// protected:

    // This is effectively a Template Method Design pattern
    // This method may not be necessary, in which case just
    // move the code to beginEvent()
    void implBegin(int a)
    {
        onBeginEvent(a);
        onBeginEvent(a, -a);
    }

    // This is effectively a Template Method Design pattern
    // This method may not be necessary, in which case just
    // move the code to endEvent()
    void implEnd(int a)
    {
        onEndEvent(a);
        onEndEvent(a, -a);
    }

    virtual void onBeginEvent(int a){}
    virtual void onBeginEvent(int a, int negativeA){}
    virtual void onEndEvent(int a){}
    virtual void onEndEvent(int a, int negativeA){}
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
    // Notice I defined these as virtual
    virtual void onBeginEvent(int a) { std::cout << a << "\n"; }
    virtual void onEndEvent(int a, int b) { std::cout << a << "==(-(" << b << "))\n"; }
};

int main() 
{
    Derived d;

    d.beginEvent(3);
    d.endEvent(9);

    return 0;
}
```

Notice that implBegin() and impleEnd() may not be necessary and
you could just do the same thing in beginEvent() and endEvent()
Here's a link to the [Template Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method) Design pattern.

Another approach would be to define Base as is, but perhaps call it EventManager, and create a class hierarchy of EventHandlers, perhaps EventBase and EventDerived. The EventHandlers could then be injected into the EventManager (via a setEventHandler() method).

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the impl method do here since they're non-virtual. You could just call the onBegin/onEnd directly from the begin/endEvent methods. Also, in the Base you should make the onBegin/onEnd methods pure virtual to avoid instant instantiating Base directly.

Comment: @chradcliffe you're correct about implBegin/End, that's why I put a comment to the effect after the code (Look for "Notice that...") I'll add a code comment. Regarding the pure virtual methods, that is indeed quite standard, but it just depends on the application and the OP can/should adapt acccordingly.

Comment: @chradcliffe regarding your comment about the impl methods being non-virtual, Im not sure what your point is, they dont need to be virtual to be able to call them. The methods that should be virtual are onBeginEvent() and onEndEvent().

Comment: The impl methods are pretty useless in this context (as you noted). If they were virtual they would be less useless. Also, when the method names contain "impl", I would generally expect them to be overridable (as a convention) and possibly protected.

Comment: in my example I do not use access modifiers for the simplicity. The idea about my code is: Class Base get some events, do some stuff with them, and pass them along in hierarchy - to Derived as new events. Impl here is just for the non-copypaste purposes. Functionality of begin and end is all the same. Maybe real scenerio helps understand this design - Base class gets call when physical collision begin/end. Normaly it would be just okej, but I need to perform some extra collision filtering (same for begin and end) and then continue...

Comment: @relaxxx, ok then, I think you can achieve this easier by using polymorphism as demonstrated in my answer. Function pointers will work, but with this sort of app in c++ they're basically non-standard these days and harder to read, whereas virtual functions are more widely accepted.